# lazy loading vs eager loading for nested comment system

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a page that has a question and six comments (parent and children). Under `lazy loading` Laravel makes exactly 12 mysql queries. I'd like to believe that it's not the best way to go about it. As the comments grow, this may introduce a problem. Take a look:

[image]

6 queries to fetch each user's info and 6 queries to fetch the comment.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
 Route::bind('comment', function($comment_id) {
     return Comment::where('id', $comment_id)
         ->whereNull('parent_id')
         ->first() ?? abort(404);
 });
```

and then I'd `lazy load` each reply like so: `$comment->children` recursively.

My question is: should I eager load all this at once, or is it fine? What is the best way to approach a situation like this?

Comment: You should do it with eager loading. Imagine your comments answers approach to 1000 comments, and your comments table is getting bigger and bigger..

Comment: @HassanShojaei yup I think you're right. this introduces the problem of n+1. eager loading is the way to go.